# What is an attribute similar to placeholder where the text is inserted rather than just a displayed watermark?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have an MVC application where I am able to create an editorfor handler in my view. I can also create a placeholder using a different property (superintendent's name for contact name). However, I actually want the editorfor box to be filled with the superintendent name rather than just as a watermark display that disappears upon clicking in the box.

Below is my current code for the editor box using the placeholder. Is there a command I can replace "placeholder" with that will achieve this?

```
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.ContactName, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", placeholder = @Html.DisplayFor(m => m.SUPERINTENDENT_FIRST_NAME) } })
```

[displayfor of superintendent](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u32x1.png)

[editorfor with placeholder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yWilD.png)

Thanks for your help,

Lindsey

Comment: Please note that the model-view-controller tag is for questions about the pattern. There is a specific tag for the ASP.NET-MVC implementation.

Comment: Set the value of `ContactName` in the GET method before you pass the model to the view -  `model.ContactName = model.SUPERINTENDENT_FIRST_NAME; return View(model);`  (and remove you `placeholder` attribute)